# How to make ggplot recognize the "repel" parameter

Tags: r, ggplot2, network-analysis

I'm trying to run the repel function in geom_nodetext and geom_edgetext but no way to make it work... I have always this error message :
Warning message:
Ignoring unknown parameters: repel .
Do you have an idea how to make it work? Example follow

```
library(NetworkToolbox)# version 1.4.1
library(dplyr)#version1.02
library(ggplot2)# version3.3.3
library(ggnetwork) #version0.5.8
library(ggrepel) #0.9.1


M1 <- as_tibble(replicate(21,sample(1:3,100,rep=TRUE))) 


colnames(M1) <- c("Wordtoolong1st", "Wordtoolong2nd", "Wordtoolong3th", "Wordtoolong4th", "Wordtoolong5th", 
                  "Wordtoolong6th","Wordtoolong7th","Wordtoolong8th","Wordtoolong9th","Wordtoolong10th",
                  "Wordtoolong11th","Wordtoolong12th","Wordtoolong13th","Wordtoolong14th","Wordtoolong15th",
                  "Wordtoolong16th","Wordtoolong17th","Wordtoolong18th","Wordtoolong19th",
                  "Wordtoolong20th","Wordtoolong21th")

M2 <- as.matrix(round(cor(M1[,],method ="kendall"),2))

MAST <- MaST(M2, normal = False)
gr4ph <-  graph.adjacency(MAST , mode = "lower",weight=TRUE) 
gg <-  ggnetwork(gr4ph, arrow.gap = 0, layout = layout_with_fr(gr4ph))

ggplot(gg, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_edges(color = "grey", alpha = 1, curvature = 0.1) +
  geom_nodes(aes(color = name), size = 6) +  theme_blank() +
  geom_nodetext(aes(label = name), color = "black", size = 3.5,repel=TRUE) +
  geom_edgetext(aes(label = weight), size = 3,alpha=0.01,repel= TRUE) + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 1, 2, 4), "cm"))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(keyheight = 0.09, keywidth = 0.09,
                              title = "Mots")) + theme(legend.position = c(-0.05, 0.14),
                                                       legend.background = element_blank(),
                                                       legend.text = element_text(size = 7))
```

Thank you

Comment: The warning says that `geom_node_text` doesn't have a `repel` parameter, it was probably not designed to work with `ggrepel`

Comment: Perhaps you want `geom_text_repel(...)` in place of `geom_node_text(...)` if you want to use the repel functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `geom_nodetext` and `geom_edgetext` calls in the example code contain the unrecognised `repel = TRUE` argument. Both geometries should be used with the same arguments as [`geom_text_repel`](https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/reference/geom_text_repel.html) to work. The arguments are also shown under e.g. `?geom_nodetext`.

The rest of the code looks fine.